# How do I transpose and simplify my SQL table with a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, subquery

**EDIT: Adding the original tables I did a full join on**

Exercise Table:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Column1 |  Column2  |  Column3   |  Column4   |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 1_e_id  | Chest     | Strength   | Situps     |
| 2_e_id  | Arms      | Strength   | Pushups    |
| 3_e_id  | Full Body | Cardio     | Running    |
| 4_e_id  | Full Body | Stretching | Gynmastics |
| 5_e_id  | Full Body | Cardio     | Swimming   |
| 6_e_id  | Legs      | Strength   | Leg Pulls  |
| 7_e_id  | Full Body | Resting    | Rest       |
| 8_e_id  | Legs      | Strength   | Lunges     |
| 9_e_id  | Arms      | Stretching | Stretching |
| 10_e_id | Legs      | Strength   | Raises     |
+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Workout Table:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+
|  Column1  | Column2 | Column3 |      Column4       |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+
| 1_w_e_id  | 1_w_id  | 1_e_id  | Strength Workout   |
| 2_w_e_id  | 1_w_id  | 2_e_id  | Strength Workout   |
| 3_w_e_id  | 1_w_id  | 4_e_id  | Strength Workout   |
| 4_w_e_id  | 2_w_id  | 3_e_id  | Stretching Workout |
| 5_w_e_id  | 2_w_id  | 6_e_id  | Stretching Workout |
| 6_w_e_id  | 2_w_id  | 7_e_id  | Stretching Workout |
| 7_w_e_id  | 2_w_id  | 9_e_id  | Stretching Workout |
| 8_w_e_id  | 3_w_id  | 2_e_id  | Glutes Workout     |
| 9_w_e_id  | 3_w_id  | 5_e_id  | Glutes Workout     |
| 10_w_e_id | 4_w_id  | 6_e_id  | Energy Workout     |
| 11_w_e_id | 4_w_id  | 8_e_id  | Energy Workout     |
| 12_w_e_id | 4_w_id  | 10_e_id | Energy Workout     |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------------------+
```

Full join: WHERE Exercise.Column1=Workout.Column3

---

SQL queries make my head spin and I can't figure this one out. I've used a full join and select to get it down to the following:

```
+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| Column1 |  Column4   |   Workouts.Column2   |   Workouts.Column4   |
+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 4_e_id  | Gymnastics | 1_w_id               | Strength Workout     |
| 1_e_id  | Situps     | 1_w_id               | Strength Workout     |
| 2_e_id  | Pushups    | 1_w_id               | Strength Workout     |
| 6_e_id  | Leg Pulls  | 2_w_id               | Stretching Workout   |
| 9_e_id  | Stretching | 2_w_id               | Stretching Workout   |
| 7_e_id  | Rest       | 2_w_id               | Stretching Workout   |
| 3_e_id  | Running    | 2_w_id               | Stretching Workout   |
| 5_e_id  | Swimming   | 3_w_id               | Glutes Workout       |
| 2_e_id  | Pushups    | 3_w_id               | Glutes Workout       |
| 10_e_id | Raises     | 4_w_id               | Energy Workout       |
| 8_e_id  | Lunges     | 4_w_id               | Energy Workout       |
| 6_e_id  | Leg Pulls  | 4_w_id               | Energy Workout       |
+---------+------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

where #_e_id is the exercise_id (Column4) and #_w_id is the workout_id (Workouts.Column4).

And I'd like to get it to the following where the exercises are organized by workout.

```
+--------------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|      Column1       |  Column2   | Column3 |  Column4   | Column5 |
+--------------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| Strength Workout   | Gymnastics | Pushups | Situps     |         |
| Stretching Workout | Leg Pulls  | Rest    | Stretching | Running |
| Glutes Workout     | Swimming   | Pushups |            |         |
| Energy Workout     | Raises     | Lunges  | Leg Pulls  |         |
+--------------------+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

How can I do this via a SQL query or rather, subquery at this point?

Comment: I'm lost.  Your original data seems to have duplicate column names.

Comment: I've used a full join can't have doesn;t exist in mysql. Please add your 2 original tables

Answer (score 0):

if instead of having the result in separate columns, you can just get the values in the same row you can use group_concat ..

```
    select  Workouts.Column4, group_conca(your_table.Column4)
    from your_table 
    group by  Workouts.Column4
```

Comment: This might work.... I'm not familiar with GROUP_CONCAT() but it looks like I can specify the concatenate myself which could accomplish close to having them in separate columns. My ultimate goal is then to use this table to fill out a table via JS and HTML.

Comment: group_concat return just a string with comma separated  value .. if you need  separated  column group_concat is not the right way  .. anyway once you have the comma separated  values in string  you could manage  these result server side for format the proper html table

Comment: See the code here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: Just wanted to give an update @scaisEdge, that worked! Thank you so much and apologies again for the confusing question.